# How do I outer join two mysql queries?

Tags: mysql

Let's say there are 4 tables , such that
`t1.id = t2.pid`
and 
`t3.id = t4.pid`

How do I fetch records where `t1.val1 != t3.val1 AND t2.val2 != t4.val2`?

Comment: put some more effort . Explain with some example

Comment: I already wrote the actual queries before and got no reply, so I am summarizing it here.

basically t1+t2 forms a recordset, say r1, similarly t3+t4 is say r2, how do I find the records which exist in r2 but not in r1?

Comment: There isn't a recent question from you that I can see that covers similar ground. You should be more careful and complete with the schema of the tables. For example, are you meant to compare records from the `(t1, t2)` record set with records from the `(t3, t4)` record set on the basis of the ID numbers? Also, do you really want records where `t1.val1 != t3.val1 OR t2.val2 != t4.val2` (but `t1.id = t3.id`)? The AND requires both values to be different (if only one is different, the data will not be selected); the OR means that if either `val1` or `val3` is different, the data will be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to find non matching records from two tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
     INNER JOIN t2
           ON t1.id = t2.pid
     LEFT OUTER JOIN t3
           ON t2.pid = t3.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN t4
           ON t3.id = t4.pid
WHERE (t1.val1 IS NULL OR t3.val1 IS NULL)
      AND (t2.val2 IS NULL OR t4.val2 IS NULL)
```

Visit: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html